# Where can I find Return to Zork?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, return-to-zork

Is it possible to purchase or download Return to Zork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dvideogames&field-keywords=return++of+zork) is still shipping this title, seperate, for Windows 9x ([1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004T9C7), [2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012CF5DC)) [DOS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BTIZSY) and even for the [mac](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BTIZSY), or as part of the [Zork Legacy Collection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0008GMVWG) (only Windows 9x)

Comment: Note that Return to Zork runs on ScummVM, so no matter which version you get, you can always play it on all platforms.

Answer (score 10):

gog.com now has a [packaged copy](http://www.gog.com/en/gamecard/the_zork_anthology) that runs really well, and it is cheap too, $5.99.

Comment: The packaged copy is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

You can play Zork I online here:

http://thcnet.net/zork/
http://www.xs4all.nl/~pot/infocom/zork1.html

There are free downloads for Zork I, II, III & The Undiscovered here for Win/Mac (no Z-interpreter required):

http://www.csd.uwo.ca/Infocom/

Also, the original mainframe version of Zork is available.  It still runs on Windows/Mac/Linux, but the content is different from the packaged version of Zork I, II & III.  The site describes it as *equivalent to Zork I + about half of Zork II + the endgame of Zork III*:

http://almy.us/dungeon.html

**EDIT** Oh sorry, I just re-read your question and realised you were specifically about Return to Zork.  My apologies.  I'll leave this here though in case a Zork enthusiast finds it useful.

Comment: Indeed, still useful info.

Answer (score 0):

[eBay](http://shop.ebay.com/?_from=R40&_trksid=m570&_nkw=return+to+zork&_sacat=See-All-Categories) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Return to Zork is available to purchase for PC on [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/585240/Return_to_Zork/) and [GOG](https://www.gog.com/en/game/return_to_zork) for $6.